# Create separate groups from a data set to iterate through (Pandas, Python 3)

Tags: python, pandas

Right now I have a large data frame within Pandas and what I'm trying to do is make a bunch of smaller groups based on a metric.  These groups will then iterated through in order to create Permutations.  This is a bit complex but here is an example:

Data Frame

```
 KW            POS      
 Cat           Noun            
 in            Prep             
 the           Prep 
 Brown         Adj              
 hat           Noun
```

**What I am trying to do** is now create 3 groups based on POS like this

```
 KW       POS           KW       POS           KW     POS
 Cat      Noun          in       Prep          Brown  Adj
 hat      Noun          Prep     Prep
```

However, The reason I believe they need to be unique groups is that these groups will then be iterated through to create word permutations -- i.e. A word from Group 1, A word from Group 2, A word from Group 3.

**The question is** 
1.) Would a grouping method like the one below be suitable to then create permutations from?

```
group = newlist.groupby(['POS'])
```

2.) If not, how do I create distinct smaller data frames that WOULD be suitable to iterate through?

Answer (score 1):

Iterating thought the groupby (or SeriesGroupby) yields the key and the subframe/series from that group:

```
In [11]: {k: v for (k, v) in g['KW']}  # equivalently/cryptically: dict(iter(g['KW']))
Out[11]:
{'Adj': 3    Brown
        Name: KW, dtype: object,
 'Noun': 0    Cat
         4    hat
         Name: KW, dtype: object,
 'Prep': 1     in
         2    the
         Name: KW, dtype: object}
```

---

IIUYC can probably look into using pandas' cartesian_product (which is a little hidden...):

```
In [12]: pd.tools.util.cartesian_product(res.values())
Out[12]:
[array(['Cat', 'Cat', 'hat', 'hat'], dtype=object),
 array(['Brown', 'Brown', 'Brown', 'Brown'], dtype=object),
 array(['in', 'the', 'in', 'the'], dtype=object)]
```

then something like map, zip, join combination should get what you want (?):

```
In [13]: map(' '.join, zip(*_))
Out[13]: ['Cat Brown in', 'Cat Brown the', 'hat Brown in', 'hat Brown the']
```